# Pull URL variable into hidden form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I add the hidden input field to a form:

```
<input name="cf_person_partner" type="hidden" value="PartnerName" />
```

With the form being hosted on a landing page with the URL:

https://wb.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Webinar_Portal?eventid=1048&partner=lucid

How can I pull the partner value (in this instance `lucid`) from the URL into the value on the hidden input field so it becomes:

```
 <input name="cf_person_partner" type="hidden" value="lucid" />
```

Note: The site is hosted using Bootstrap and no Javascript is currently running (so I'll need to add this in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pull this value from URL (URL obviously being `window.location.href`)

```
var url = "https://wb.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Webinar_Portal?eventid=1048&partner=lucid";

var partnerName = url.split("partner=")[1];

document.querySelector("[name='cf_person_partner']").value = partnerName;
```

**DEMO**

```js
    var url = "https://wb.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Webinar_Portal?eventid=1048&partner=lucid";
    
    var partnerName = url.split("partner=")[1];

    document.querySelector("[name='cf_person_partner']").value = partnerName;
```

```html
<input name="cf_person_partner" type="hidden" value="PartnerName" />
```

if the partner parameter is not necessarily the coming last on URL, then add this line

```
var partnerName = url.split("partner=")[1];
partnerName = partnerName.split( "&" )[0];
```

Comment: Thanks so I'd need to add:

`<script>
var url = "https://wb.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Webinar_Portal?eventid=1048&partner=lucid";

var partnerName = url.split("partner=")[1];
partnerName = partnerName.split( "&" )[0];

document.querySelector("[name='cf_person_partner']").value = partnerName;
</script>`

Plus add Javascript to the body such as:

 `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` and no changes would be needed on the actual HTML input line?

Comment: @SamJefferies html input markup doesn't need to change. But your URL will be the value of `location.href`.

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 apologies, I'm very fresh to Javascript. I can't see the `location.href` in the script you provided, is this something I need to add in?

Comment: @SamJefferies Nope, it is not in my code, but you may need it. Simply replace `var URL = "your URL" ` with `var URL = location.href;`

Comment: Gotcha I see! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from url first

```
var partnerName = url.split("partner=")[1];
```

Assign it to the hidden field, make sure you add up an it access it, you can access with name too.

```
 <input name="cf_person_partner" id="hiddenValue" type="hidden" value="PartnerName" />
```

and update the value using jquery as :

```
 $('#hiddenValue').val("lucid");
```

you can call have javascript events to trigger this change. May be a function which will have the line that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the value from url, You can do this using `location` object:

Example:

```
var partnerValue = location.search.split("partner=");
```

then you may set the name to the field :

```
$("[name='cf_person_partner']").value(partnerValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below Javascript code:

**Common function for getting URL parameters:**

```
function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
```

and assign to hidden field like below:

```
document.querySelector("[name='cf_person_partner']").value = getUrlVars()["partner"];
```

hope it will help you, Thanks